# Silverlight 2 TextBlock ignores MaxWidth

Tags: silverlight, width, textblock

I am using Silverlight 2 to dynamically add a TextBlock to a Canvas.  I set the MaxWidth of the TextBlock but it ignores this value and displays a string longer than the MaxWidth value.

```
TextBlock label=new TextBlock();
label.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty,Convert.ToDouble(x+3));
label.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, Convert.ToDouble(y + 1));
label.Width = DisplayWidth - 6;
label.Height = DisplayHeight - 2;
label.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.NoWrap;
label.MaxWidth = DisplayWidth-6;
label.MinWidth = DisplayWidth-6;
label.Text = this.Title;
label.Margin = new Thickness(3.0);
baseCanvas.Children.Add(label);
```

What do I have to do to get the TextBlock to restrict its width to a specific value?  Ideally I'll add conditional ellipses too (i.e. ...).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would seem that `MaxWidth` on a `TextBlock` is ineffectual when the `TextBlock` is a direct child of a `Canvas`.  I can't quite fathom why that would be so.  However the solution would be to place the `TextBlock` in a `Border`:-

```
TextBlock label=new TextBlock(); 
label.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty,Convert.ToDouble(x+3)); 
label.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, Convert.ToDouble(y + 1)); 
label.Width = DisplayWidth - 6; 
label.Height = DisplayHeight - 2; 
label.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.NoWrap; 
label.MaxWidth = DisplayWidth-6; 
label.MinWidth = DisplayWidth-6; 
label.Text = this.Title; 
label.Margin = new Thickness(3.0); 
Border border = new Border();
border.Child = label;
baseCanvas.Children.Add(border);
```

The `Border` will honor the `MaxWidth` of the `TextBlock` but since it is given no thickness the border itself is invisible.